# Dual boot screen win 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had Windows 10 in my laptop. Then I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and when I started my laptop I found dual boot screen, so always I choose  Ubuntu.
The last time  ubuntu did update then restart then the dual boot screen did not appear but directly Windows 10 works.
what should I do to have the dual boot screen again.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it was not a Windows update. Windows will reset itself as first in boot order with updates and turn on fast start up. Post this: `sudo efibootmgr -v`. You may just need to go into your UEFI and reset boot order.

Answer (score 0):

If your *dual boot screen* mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMSS6.jpg) which is called `GRUB` (GRand Unified Bootloader), then this answer might help you. I assume that your are not able to get into Ubuntu and you need to solve this from Windows. This helped me when I  was new to Ubuntu.

- In Windows, go to the menu.

  [image]
- Search for Command Prompt, right click on it to run it as administrator

  [image]
- In here, copy paste the command below:

  ```
  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
  ```
- Restart and you’ll be welcomed by the familiar Grub screen or *dual boot screen*.

Let me know if it helps.

Source: [It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/)