# Ubuntu not showing up after installation (Dual-boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb, grub-efi

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my system. I used the following Youtube tutorial and it worked well.(Used .iso image and USB as bootable device).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNeJvujdB-0

I have Windows 10 (64 bit) and now I installed Ubuntu. The problem is after installation, when I restarted my system(USB removed), it directly boots into Windows. I don't see the GRUB menu to make choices!

I checked in my disk management window and it shows 20.00 GB healthy partition and it means Ubuntu is installed on my HDD but it just doesn't ask me to choose.

In the bios menu, under Boot, I only find Windows boot loader, Toshiba HDD(My main hard drive that has Windows and Ubuntu installed), USB HDD, USB FDD, and some other(no Ubuntu).

I really want to start working with Ubuntu. If you need any other information to solve this, please ask.

This is not a big problem for so many of you experts! I tried really alot to find a solution and at the end I posted here. I really can't try everything as I don't wanna mess up anything!

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: What brand/model system? Also what video card/chip? Acer requires "trust" in UEFI, Sony, HP and several others require work arounds. Most will let you boot from f12 or f10 one time UEFI boot menu. Did you install in UEFI boot mode, not 35 year old BIOS mode which UEFI can emulate.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1041346/816190 it may help

Comment: @oldfred Model- Acer Aspire E15,  Intel i5 processor, Nvidia 940M GPU. Yes I installed it in UEFI boot mode. But In the boot order, should I see Ubuntu/the disk partition it is installed in? because I don't see it. But I am pretty sure Ubuntu's installation was successful! I just can't choose.

Comment: All Acer requires you to enable "trust" on the .efi boot files from within UEFI. And most Acer need UEFI update from Acer. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/870022/how-to-get-grub-boot-option/870074 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003  All of above are essentially the same, just some explain it slightly differently. You also may need nomodeset boot parameter.

Comment: @Kulfy It worked! now I can dual boot! Thank you so much!